# Javascript capture errors

Tags: javascript

I'm using ***window.error*** to try to capture all client side errors.

It's working fine with Javascript errors but It doesn't capture all errors like Network Errors, or AJAX errors.

This is my code (**I can't use jQuery**, so is not possible to use .ajaxError):

```
window.onerror = function(messageOrEvent, source, lineno, colno, error) {
    console.log("Captured: " + messageOrEvent)
}
```

This is the result:
[image]

Anyone knows a way to capture ALL errors on the client side?

Thanks

Comment: If the ajax calls are jquery may do {error:err=>throw err}

Comment: I must do it globally. I can't edit every single function. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Probably override some XMLHttpRequest.prototype function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe hook over the default request object:

```
(function(orig){
   window.XMLHttpRequest=function(...args){
    var instance=new orig(...args);
    instance.addEventListener("readyStateChange",function(){
     if(instance.status!==200){
       throw new Error(instance.status+":"+instance.statusText);
     }
    });
  return instance;
 };
})(XMLHttpRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for. What is suposed to go in ...args?

Comment: @marcos Aguayo same as .apply(arguments), have a look at *rest parameter*

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way. This is my code. I think that this capture all errors.

```
    // JavaScript Errors
    window.onerror = function(messageOrEvent, source, lineno, colno, error) {
        console.log("Captured: " + messageOrEvent)
    }

    // 404 FILES
    window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }, true);

    // AJAX Errors
    var open = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open,
      send = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

    function openReplacement(method, url, async, user, password) {
      this._url = url;
      return open.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    function sendReplacement(data) {
      if(this.onreadystatechange) {
        this._onreadystatechange = this.onreadystatechange;
      }
      this.onreadystatechange = onReadyStateChangeReplacement;
      return send.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    function onReadyStateChangeReplacement() {

      // CAPTURE HERE.
      if(this.status != 200){
        console.log(this.responseURL + " " + this.status + " " + this.statusText);
      }

      if(this._onreadystatechange) {
        return this._onreadystatechange.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    }

    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = openReplacement;
    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = sendReplacement;
```